# UIButton corner radius not working properly in CustomClass

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, cornerradius

I've make a custom class for `UIButton` but in small screen devices e.g. `iPhone 5s` `cornerRadius` not working properly

[image: Button looks Like This]

You've to looks closer to see the `UiButton`'s `cornerRadius` is not perfectly rounded

```
class customRoundButton: UIButton
{
    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = (self.layer.frame.height / 2)
        self.layer.borderColor = fontColor.defualtBlue.cgColor
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
}
```

Comment: Move the line `self.layer.cornerRadius = (self.layer.frame.height / 2)` to `layoutSubviews` instead. You can also remove the line `self.layer.layoutIfNeeded()`.

Comment: exactly as mentioned by @AndréSlotta set your corner radius in the `func layoutSubviews()` method

Comment: Bad luck, won't work.

Comment: @Bhavesh Can you please show your updated code then?

Comment: @Bhavesh there is no luck involved here. Did you try it?

Comment: My problem already solve by @AndréSlotta .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Setting the `cornerRadius` in `awakeFromNib` is too early. Use `layoutSubviews` instead:

```
class CustomRoundButton: UIButton {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        layer.cornerRadius = layer.frame.height / 2
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.height * 0.50    
}
```

So by the time your custom UIButton is going to be added to the subviews it will know it bounds and you just have to assign the corner radius to be the half of bounds height.

Answer (score 0):

Better use `IBDesignable` for this :

```
@IBDesignable
class RoundedButton: UIButton {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 3.0 {
        didSet {
            self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        }
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        self.setupView()
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setupView()
    }

    func setupView() {
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this question here and found for me what worked best in Swift 5 is setting the corner radius in `awakeFromNib` inside `Disptatch.main.async` When using `layoutSubviews` or `setNeedsLayout` the closure is called for every little change or movement. This might work for some use cases. I have not tried that with the above example.

My code looks like this:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    imageView.layer.masksToBounds = false
    imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = self.imageView.bounds.height / 2.0
        }
    }
```